# Unsafe C functions and the replacement

Tags: c

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I research in the site but can't find any consolidated post for this problem. There are many unsafe functions in C that can lead to buffer overflow and they have the safe functions to replace them. I have a few:

- `gets()` === replace by === `fgets()`
- `sprintf()` === replace by === ?
- `strcat()` === replace by === ?
- `strcpy()` === replace by === `strncpy()`
- `vsprintf()` === replace by === `vsnprintf()`

Also, I stuck with the unsafe byte copy and unsafe byte input code below. How can I fix the problems?
Why does this code have vulnerability?

```
int copy_buf (char *to, int pos, char *from, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<len;<i++){
         to[pos] = from [i];
         pos++;
    }
    return pos
}
```

For the byte input, is the `fread()` unsafe function? Why does the buffer overflow happen here?

```
short read_chunk(FILE fil, char *to)
{
    short len;
    fread(&len, 2, 1, fil);
    fread(to, 1, len, fil);
    return len;
}
```

Comment: I would count neither `strcpy` nor `strcat` as unsafe. Also, `strncpy` is a specialized tool for putting a string into a fixed-size-buffer and zeroing the rest (if any).

Comment: Replacing `strcat()` with `strncat()` is going to break more code than it fixes.  What is the length that you specify to `strncat()`?  (Hint: it is _not_ the length of the string you are copying to!)

Comment: Your `copy_buf` is a nightmare-vision of a distorted and bent `memcpy`. Also, read the [man-page for `fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwrite.3.html).

Comment: Note that "safe" is a relative term.  Merely not overflowing a buffer doesn't make something "safe" from a behavior point of view.  For instance: if a filename is being passed around and it's `blah/blah/bar.txt` and your buffer doesn't overflow but truncates to `blah/blah/bar` then that might be used for reading/writing/deleting something unexpected on the wrong file.  The real safe string "functions" aren't functions but moving up to C++ and the class `std::string`, consider reading the opening section of [Learning Standard C++ as a new language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf).

Comment: As I read in a book, they list those 2 functions : strcpy or strcat (char *dest, char *src) as unsafe functions. They append and copy contents of string src to string dest. On my opinion, they didn't check on the amount of data copied, that can lead to buffer overflow. I don't know, I'm not a C programmer so I'm not sure.

Comment: @KL84: Yes, MS wants to replace half the C library. Don't give in to them.

Comment: You can't use `strcpy()` safely unless you know the length of the target buffer and the length of the string to be copied - that is true.  Similar comments apply to `strcat()`; you need to know how long the data is in the target string, how much space is left, and the length of the string to be added.  If you know that, all is safe.  If you don't know that, neither `strncpy()` nor `strncat()` is safe either.  Note that `strncpy()` has surprising side effects.  It the target string is 4 KiB and the source is 3 characters, you're still going to write 4 KiB of data, all but 3 bytes of them zeros.

Comment: Your question is three questions. You might like to pose them seperatly.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the List of Some unsafe C Functions with their replaced New Function

- strcpy -> strncpy -> strlcpy/strcpy_s
- strcat -> strncat -> strlcat/strcat_s
  -strtok
- sprintf -> snprintf
- vsprintf -> vsnprintf
- gets -> fgets/gets_s
- makepath -> _makepath_s (MSDN)
- _splitpath -> _splitpath_s (MSDN)
- scanf/sscanf -> sscanf_s (MSDN)
- snscanf -> _snscanf_s (MSDN)
- strlen -> strnlen_s (MSDN)

Certain functions behave in dangerous ways regardless of how they are used. Functions in this category were often implemented without taking security concerns into account. The gets() function is unsafe because it does not perform bounds checking on the size of its input.

An attacker can easily send arbitrarily-sized input to gets() and overflow the destination buffer. Similarly, the >> operator is unsafe to use when reading into a statically-allocated character array because it does not perform bounds checking on the size of its input. An attacker can easily send arbitrarily-sized input to the >> operator and overflow the destination buffer.

The code below calls gets() to read information into a buffer.

```
char buf[24];
printf("Please enter your name and press <Enter>\n");
gets(buf);
...
}
```

However, the programmer uses the function gets() which is inherently unsafe because it blindly copies all input from STDIN to the buffer without checking size. This allows the user to provide a string that is larger than the buffer size, resulting in an overflow condition

You can read More about Dangers in C/C++ further here..

1. <s>http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-class/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/dangers-c.html</s>
2. http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/
3. http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/26-unsafe-languages.html

Comment: `gets()` is unsafe and no longer available since C11 so discussing its weaknesses is of diminishing importance going forward.  Most of these suggested replacements trade one set of un-safeness for others.   C is programing without a net.  Select function usage will not save code from weak programming.

Comment: The first link of further reading material has changed to(now with version number): https://dwheeler.com/secure-programs/3.71/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/dangers-c.html

Answer (score 7):

`strncpy` is *not* a safe replacement for `strcpy`. In fact, these functions are unrelated, despite the unfortunate similarity in the naming. Safe replacement for `strcpy` is a non-standard function `strlcpy` provided by some *nix implementations as an extension. Usage of `strncpy` for "safe" string copying is an immediate sign of incompetent code.

Another group of unsafe functions (albeit unsafe for a different reason) are functions from `ato..` group: `atoi`, `atof`, `atol` and so on. These functions trigger undefined behavior in case of overflow. Their safe replacements are functions from `strto...` group: `strtol`, `strtod` and such.

There's nothing "unsafe" about your `copy_buf` function in a sense that it provides the calling code with all means necessary to perform a safe call to `copy_buf`. The responsibility to pass the correct values in this case is placed on the caller.

Your `read_chunk` function is much more dangerous, since the calling code has no way of knowing how big the buffer is supposed to be. There's no perfect solution for this function that would work well with a buffer passed from outside. It makes sense to at least make the calling code to pass the size of the buffer as well. This will allow `read_chunk` to make sure the buffer is not overflowed. Also, `read_chunk` should inform the calling code about incomplete reads. You should provide the caller with means to complete the read.

Comment: The `read_chunk()` code should also be detecting short or erroneous reads (check the return value from `fread()`), and needs a mechanism to report them.  It should also check that the length read fits into the space passed for it to read into.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for your answer. I still confuse on both functions. First, the copy_buf, why Mosa said this {int copy_buf (char *to, int pos, char *from, int len)} is unsafe and you say not.
The read_chunk(), so the buffer overflow will happen when the fil size is bigger than len size, am I correct?

Comment: @KL84: It isn't my answer; I just gave AdreyT's answer a minor tweak. I said nothing about `copy_buf()`. If I were to say anything, I'd say that it is a complex interface. There's no obvious advantage to providing `base` and `offset` as opposed to just `&base[offset]`. So, the destination should be a single argument, rather than the pair. It then more or less matches other copy functions, adapted to `char`.  You still have to know that there's enough space in `to` for `len` bytes more data.

Comment: @KL84: As for `read_buf()`, there's no way for it to protect your code because it has no idea how much space there is in the `to` buffer, so it cannot tell how much data is safe. You also don't check that either of the input operations succeeds, a crucial step.  I'm not keen on the use of `2` in the first call; it should be `sizeof(len)`.  It isn't clear how you should report a short read, or whether you should loop in an attempt to deal with short reads.  You're using a signed length, so it can't go higher than 32767 reliably.

Comment: `strlcpy` has a rather unfortunate return value which means that it, like `strncpy`, generally does more work than you would like it to. If you can use C20, adapt `memccpy` to your usecase.

Comment: what does this answer mean by `strncpy` is not related to `strcpy`? Their names are similar, but more importantly, they seem to do pretty similar things, and the only obvious difference is that the former has an additional `int` param?

Comment: ah I found the answer [here in a blog post](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html). `strncpy` actually pads the destination with extra 0-terminators.

Answer (score 2):

- sprintf === replace by === snprintf: Because snprintf you have to use like this `(char *dest, size_t destsize, const char *format, ...).` You have to give the max size of the destination and destination will be has `\0`. So it will not be written above  `dest[destsize - 1]`.
- strcat === replace by === snprintf: See above

```
int copy_buf (char *to, int pos, char *from, int len)
```

This method is unsafe, because you use `len` for both char pointer. Maybe there will be a segmentation fault, because your for-loop can go beyond one of the pointer. Better to use two variable for each pointer.

Comment: :Can you explain more why copy_buf is unsafe? The way I understand is if the size of `to` larger than `pos+len`, so the program is fine. Otherwise, `copy_buf` function is fail. Am I correct?

Comment: AndreyT said that copy_buf is not unsafe, because the caller has the responsibility to call the method correctly. But I think, that the programmer has to handle all messy input. Maybe you want to use the code in a high critical environment.
Yes you are correct. But I think it is not good to handle parameter (pos) input like that. You change the value of the parameter. You can maybe declare a new local variable and assign the value of pos to the new variable etc.
You must also be sure that the size of "to" and "from" are not smaller than len.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf => snprintf
strcat => strncat
```

Comment: @KL84 In general do not edit your question to incorporate a given answer (or make fundamental changes to your question that invalidate any prior answer).  If you feel no answer contains the information to fully address your question, you can always post an aggregate summary answer of your own and accept that (though you won't get any points for that acceptance).

Answer (score 0):

The only unsafe function listed is `gets()` as the uncertainties it introduces cannot be maneuvered around <sup>*1</sup>.

All other functions are safe if used correctly.

---

<sup>*1 That why it had been removed from the C Standard.</sup>

Comment: +1 Well said (Although I find errant user input to `scanf()` recovery troublesome to the point of just not using `scanf()`.)